# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] wiping form, not posting

Tags: php

I'm trying to post a form to a URL as below, however it simply just wipes the form and doesn't post anything when clicking submit.

Any ideas?  I can't see anything wrong so need another set of eyes.

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="code" class="input" placeholder="Enter Passcode Here..">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If I put 12345667890 in the Code input and click submit, I would expect the URL to show
www.domain.com/index.php?code=1234567890.  This does not happen, it simply wipes the form and loads www.domain.com/index.php

Comment: Your form action sends the data back to itself. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yep, I'm going to get the data from the URL but at the moment it won't even post to it.

Comment: at the top of the code, type <?=$_POST['code'];?> and see if you get a result.

Comment: @K20GH - that code works for me - it's posting the contents of `code` back to the form.

Comment: can you post the full code ?

Comment: If I add in $code = $_GET['code']; 
echo $code; it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: Added in a bit more detail.

Comment: @K20GH - for that to work, you need to change the action to GET

Comment: Changed it to GET and its putting the variables in the URL.  However now it gives me a 500 error.  To everyone saying "post full code", there is no more code!

Comment: @K20GH so IT DOES WHAT U CODE: NOTHING

Comment: @K20GH I posted a **working answer** below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In using `passcode.php` as a filename, with an example input of `12345`, will output:
`http://www.example.com/passcode.php?code=12345` as intended.

**Here is the fully tested and working code:**

```
<form class="form-inline" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="code" class="input" placeholder="Enter Passcode Here..">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You must use the `GET` method to achieve this, not `POST`.

**To echo the URL's full string, use the following:**

```
<?php

$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;

?>

<form class="form-inline" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="code" class="input" placeholder="Enter Passcode Here..">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In using `12345` as input, will output (echo): `http://www.example.com/passcode.php?code=12345`

Comment: `<button type="submit"` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your form is `method="post"`.

POST data is encoded into the **body** of the HTTP request, not into the URL. It will still be accessible to the server side script that the form is being submitted to.

If you want the data to show up in the URL, use `method="GET"`.

(But see [the specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) for reasons why you should use POST or GET and use those to decide which you should be using).

Answer (score 0):

At this moment the form does exactly what you wrote it to do.
It submits the form to the same page. You then don't do anything with the post data. And the script simply returns the same html again.

Comment: I'm posting the data though so it should post to the URL.  If using code 1234567890 it should post https://domain.com/submit.php?code=1234567890.  It doesn't, it simply wipes the form and the URL stays as https://domain.com/submit.php

Comment: Change method= post to method = get

Comment: If I use GET, how would I pull code from the URL? $var = $_GET['code']; ?

Comment: @K20GH read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) and [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php)

Comment: @K20GH How to `pull the code`? See my answer with 2 pieces of code inside it. You can then decide how to use it, to save to file/database, that will be up to you.